# Enclosing the output of a function in double quotes using Powershell

Tags: powershell, double-quotes

I have a simple function that returns a string

```
function Test() {
  return "'Hello World!!'"
}
```

I can time how long it takes to execute the task and display the output using the following:

```
Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host $(Test)})"
'Hello World!!'
Elapsed : 00:00:00.0114593
```

If I want I can use following command to include the output in single quotes:

```
Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host "'$(Test)'"})"
''Hello World!!''
Elapsed : 00:00:00.0063993
```

But if I want to include the output in *double quotes* it seems to get messy.  I tried using [double double quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) but that didn't work...

```
PS C:\Users\tolcher_m\Documents\Files\usr\etc\usr> Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host ""$(Test)""})"
'Hello World!!'
Elapsed : 00:00:00.0076760
```

I did manage to get the result I wanted using the code below:

```
Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host "$('"')$(Test)$('"')"})"
"'Hello World!!'"
Elapsed : 00:00:00.0105664
```

However this looks very messy, I assume there must be better way to do it?

Thank you

Updated:

Trying to escape the double quotes doesn't seem to work.

```
Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host "`"$(Test)`""})"
 'Hello World!!' 
Elapsed : 00:00:00.0079815
```

Comment: The escape character in PowerShell is the backtick (`\``), which can also be used to escape double quotes.

Comment: I should have said I had tried that so I have updated question to show the result.

Comment: I think this is just a smidgen too complicated for the PowerShell parser to make sense of. I'd just get rid of this multi-level embedding and write ``Write-Host ("Elapsed: " + (Measure-Command { Write-Host "`"$(Test)`"" }))``. For extra clarity I'd even consider breaking that up in two lines, one to execute & measure and one to print (``$m = Measure-Command { Write-Host "`"$(Test)`"" } ; Write-Host "Elapsed: $m"``). Don't be too hung up on squeezing out oneliners.

Comment: Or use the `-f` format operator like with `Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host ('"{0}"' -f (Test))})"`

Comment: Just a personal preference but I found `Write-Host ("Elapsed: " + (Measure-Command{Write-Host "\`"$(Test)\`""}))` a little easier to understand, and I finally figured out how to quote back ticks on a comment (you need to escape them using a backslash!)   I did stick with a _one liner_ this time as it is easier to cut and paste...

Comment: After a bit of messing about I came up with the following:  `Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host ""\`""$(Test)""\`"" })"`  (yet another alternative!)

Comment: Simply change your Test-function to return '"Hello World!!"' and Write-Host "Elapsed : $(Measure-Command{Write-Host $(Test)})" Shows the right Output.